# Large set of image folder to dataset

Tags: python, pandas, image, machine-learning, h5py

I have a folder with a large number of image set. I want a database with each image as row and RGB values as columns. What is the easiest way to do that for a deep-learning application? A coded example is appreciated.

Comment: what have you done so far? Where exactly is your bottleneck?

Comment: You said it, extract each file's RGB and put them together. You can use [openCV](https://opencv.org/) for that purpose.